# Why is my code visible in the browser?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

This is an html.erb file. When I run the generator and view it in my browser, this is what I see:

```
<% ['fun', 'money', 'make interesting programs', 'start my own website', 'be cool'].each do |reason| %>
I like to <%= reason %>
<% end %>
```

Instead of a list of all the reasons I provided for wanting to learn Rails.

Why aren't they being output the way I'd like them to?

Comment: How do you view it in the browser? What do you do?

Comment: I simply drag the file from my Finder into Google Chrome.

Comment: You need to start the server first.

Comment: @drichards2013: I'd suggest you one of countless '15 minutes blog in Rails' articles as it seems you need to understand the very basics of webdevelopment.

Comment: Try working through http://ruby.railstutorial.org/ and then coming back with questions when you know a bit more. :)

Answer (score 0):

make sure that your file is **file.html.erb** and not just **file.html**

Also make sure that you have the rails server started and the path is `localhost:3000/file` or your rout to the file

Answer (score 0):

The below code can help you please check:

```
<%= ["fun", "money", "make interesting programs", "start my own website", "be cool"].each do |a| %>                                                                   
  <%=  "I like to #{a}"  %> 
<%end%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to start a Ruby on Rails server on your machine and access the page thru the server (http://localhost:3000) not opening the file directly.

Make sure you place the files in the right locations and you provide a route to your page.

The easiest way to create the required files (and have them placed at the right place) is the use the provided rails generators.

Assuming you have created your Ruby on Rails project (rails new simpletest), you should have something like:

[image: Empty Ruby on Rails project]

The next step is to generate the test controller and the index method associated with that controller:

[image: The rails generate controller command]

Few notes:

- A new route has been added to the config/routes.rb file
- A new file named test_controller.rb has been added
- A new directory has been added in the views
- A file named index.html.erb has been added to that directory

My directory structure looks like this:

[image: Once the controller test has been added]

Now it's time to start the Ruby on Rails server:

[image]

And check with your Web browser if the test/index.html.erb loads propeperly:

[image: Web page]

And now, I copy/paste your code:

With a slight addition (adding <P> tag)

[image: Edited code]

Time to test again:

[image: Final]